# Clicking on table content and make it editable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a table with fetched data from the database.
I need a way to, by clicking on a specific cell, make the content on that cell editable and then save it into the database.
Here is my code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="tabela1">
<tr><th>Data</th><th>Empresa</th><th>Função / Descrição</th></tr>
<tbody>
<?php
   while ($pptable = mysql_fetch_array($pp, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $ppdata=$pptable['data'];
    $ppemp=$pptable['empresa'];
    $ppdesc=$pptable['descricao'];
    foreach ($pptable as $ppdata){
        echo "<tr><td>".$ppdata."</td><td>".$ppemp."</td><td>".$ppdesc."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks !

Comment: What you need here is something like [EJS Tree Grid](http://www.treegrid.com/treegrid/www/)

Comment: What's your ([relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) rendered HTML as seen by the browser, as it appears in 'view source'? Your php is, largely, irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use native javascript but here is a jQuery plugin that is easy to use and you can do what you are looking for with ease.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Check out the demo page here:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Comment: Precisely what i needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the value into an input

```
$('#tabela1 tr td').on('click',function(){
var prev_text = $(this).text();
$(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + prev_text + '"/>');
$(this).focus();
});

$('#tabela1 tr td input').focusout(function(){
// Return to previous make validate/ajax call here.
});
```

Not Tested but that would be the basic logic behind.

But using existing Library would be better or use what @Ozmah said in his comment.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your html code. i think you mean '<input type="text" value="' + prev_text +'" />'

Comment: @andreas yeah fixed i just realized >.<